# Вернуть список объектов в заданных координатах

Tags: python

Задание:
написать функцию, которая будет возвращать список объектов в заданных координатах.

Дано:

```
game_objects = {
    ('wall', 0): {'position': (0, 0), 'passable': False, 'interactable': False, 'char': '#'},
    ('wall', 1): {'position': (0, 1), 'passable': False, 'interactable': False, 'char': '#'},
    ('player',): {'position': (1, 1), 'passable': True, 'interactable': True, 'char': '@', 'coins': 0},
    ('soft_wall', 11): {'position': (1, 4), 'passable': False, 'interactable': True, 'char': '%'}
}
```

Наш код:

```
def get_objects_by_coords(position):
    for i in game_objects.values():
            if i['position'] == position:
                for j in game_objects.keys():
                    return [j]
            return []
```

Пример вывода:

```
get_objects_by_coords((1, 1)) == [('player',)]
get_objects_by_coords((2, 1)) == []
```

Проблема: код проходит только по первым значениям словаря, как можно их объединить? Или можно в этом случае использовать функцию get()?

Comment: _наш код_, наш это чей?

Comment: мой и одногруппника

Comment: второй return сдвиньте на уровень for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас второй return прерывает цикл и ключ вы странно добываете

```
def get_objects_by_coords(position):
    ret = []
    for k,i in game_objects.items():
            if i['position'] == position:
                    ret.append(k)
    return ret

print(get_objects_by_coords((1, 1))) #  == [('player',)]
print(get_objects_by_coords((2, 1))) # == []
```

Comment: assertion error

Comment: получается, в коде учитывается тот факт, что в одной точке может быть несколько предметов, и эта функция их все возвращает

Comment: так вам надо все? сейчас, как видите, после первого совпадения return стоит

Comment: а нужно continue? пока координаты не перестанут удовлетворять условию?

Comment: надо собирать в лист, вероятно и потом его возращать - сделал в ответе такую версию

Comment: Спасибо, СРАБОТАЛО!